# How to Change 1,2,3,4 to F1,F2,F3,F4 using Crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

My question is how can I convert these numbers `1,2,3,4` to `F1,F2,F3,F4` using Crystal report on formula fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming this is a string field called {MyDelimitedNumbers}, use something like:

```
"F" + Replace({MyDelimitedNumbers}, ",", ",F")
```